# Should I care about culture, when my app will not emigrate?

Tags: c#, winforms, resharper, cultureinfo

ReSharper wants to change this:

```
platypusID = DuckbillValues[i - 1].ToString();
```

..to this:

```
platypusID = DuckbillValues[i - 1].ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Since the chances are great that my app will only be used in the U.S., which of the following would I be to acquiesce:

```
1) Smart
2) Dumb
3) Neither smart nor dumb
4) Smart, but not for that reason
5) Dumb, but not for that reason
```

Comment: You already know the answer. If you're looking for a little peer-pressure to push you into writing better code, here's one: 1. On the other hand, if you're looking to us to back up your lazy inclination, maybe someone else will oblige.

Comment: Yes you should, possibly not right this minute. Experience suggests the minute you decide not to deal with this sort of issue, someone important won't be using a US culture.

Comment: How can you be sure that it will only be used in the US by people using a US locale? At the very least, the cost should negligible enough that preparing for copies to shipped to Japan or Mexico or Canada or used by someone in the US who finds that locale most comfortable is a win.

Comment: You're using a tool that *will make the change for you*.  Why would you not want it to help you make better code?

Comment: I’m curious: Does ReSharper suggest the change because it realizes that the value will be used as an ID, or does it always recommend `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`? Because the latter behaviour seems incorrect when the string is a natural number that will be displayed to the user.

Comment: @Douglas: In this case, the ID will always be several positive digits, such as 12345 or 31442 or 091101, etc.

Comment: @ClayShannon If you want the last ID you listed to be a valid one, you need to change your code... You won't get a leading zero without explicit formatting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Since the chances are great that my app will only be used in the U.S.

Even if you're app is only used in the US, there's always a chance, if you're targeting a large audience, that a user could customize their regional settings or have their system setup using a different region.

Using `InvariantCulture` will be safe no matter what you're user does.  Given that this is setting an "id", I, personally, would most likely force the culture to `InvariantCulture` in order to guarantee that I won't get a strange result later.

This also makes it easier in the future to support other regions... You never know what will happen later with your code, whether in this application or in others.

Also - since you're using ReSharper, it's already warning you about this.  You're already there.  It's actually easier to comply with good coding standards than it would be to ignore the warning, which makes it difficult to think of a reason NOT to specify the culture.